# WP7.1 Missing resources

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I start the project in VS2010, even if I choose wp7.1 as a target, the project start with the 7.0 OS version. As soon I switch from the properties to "Target Windows Phone OS Version"  WP7.1, some resources references apparently becames broken, ie:

```
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
```

and others are not found in designer mode. If I launch the app in the emulator, it works. Unfortunately I can't see my page in designer mode, that is quite annoying. Any idea ?

Comment: How are you switching properties to WP7.1?

Comment: I just switched the "project properties" to 7.1 what else have I to change ?

Comment: It sounds like the 7.1 sdk (update?) didn't install correctly. Have you tried reinstalling it.

Comment: @Matt Lacey it could be, since the update setup compalin about missing VS express ( it is missing because I've the standard one )

Comment: @FelicePollano Sounds like you need to debug (log) the install and see what is or isn't being installed correctly.